# How to wrap a mysql stored function in a transaction

Tags: mysql, function, transactions

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS my_func;
DELIMITER ||
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(arg_id INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
BEGIN
    DECLARE local_id INT;
    DECLARE local_name VARCHAR(200);
    START TRANSACTION; /* <-- this is allowed */
        SELECT      id, name
            INTO    local_id, local_name
            FROM    table
            WHERE   id = arg_id
            FOR UPDATE;
        SELECT my_other_function(local_name) INTO local_name;
        UPDATE table SET name = local_name;
    COMMIT; /* <-- this is not allowed
        and yields an "Explicit or
        implicit commit is not
        allowed..." error */
    RETURN local_name;
END||
DELIMITER ;
```

Are return statements implicit commits?

How are you supposed to ensure that a certain function runs **as a** transaction?

Wrap it in a transaction?

```
START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT my_func(33); /* <-- no transaction statements inside the function */
COMMIT;
```

Start the transaction inside the function and commit?

```
SELECT my_func(33); /* <-- contains only the START TRANSACTION line */
COMMIT;
```

Also i've researched the issue and found some info that said something along the lines of: "statements in stored functions are not guaranteed to be executed in the declared order which can make binary logging (and implicitly replication) inconsistent".

Comment: Do you mean "How to avoid an _implicit_ commit?" You can avoid an _explicit_ commit by removing "commit;".

Comment: No, the title has a funny wording that I couldn't rephrase. What I'm asking is, **if I need the commit inside the function but that is not permitted, what is the canonical/recommended way to achieve the same goal... meaning the entire function call and subsequent function calls running inside a transaction?**

Comment: I know that dropping the COMMIT will make the code valid, and no errors arise but if I have the START TRANSACTION with no commit will it autocommit on return? If I SELECT FOR UPDATE will it release the rows after function end? If not, the when do I call the commit outside of the function?

Comment: I've updated the question name, perhaps it's clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to use this before and it worked for me:

**Option 1**

```
SET autocommit = {0 | 1}
```

After you have completed what you want to do, you can re-enable it or call an explicit commit.

**Option 2**
To disable autocommit mode implicitly for a single series of statements, use the START TRANSACTION statement:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT @A:=SUM(salary) FROM table1 WHERE type=1;
UPDATE table2 SET summary=@A WHERE type=1;
COMMIT;
```

I got this from the mysql website itself - [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/commit.html)

---

For your situation, I would think that setting autocommit to false before the function would do the trick (starting a transaction is the same thing if you look at the description of it above). That way, during the transaction, your function, it doesn't autcommit.

Comment: So basically I either issue a `START TRANSACTION;` `SELECT my_function();` `COMMIT;` or I use `SET autocommit = 0;` inside the function code and `COMMIT;` outside the function code?

Comment: Yes as far as I can tell from the documentation and my experience it seems right. I haven't done this exactly but seems right.

Comment: And about the other question, unreliable binary logging behaviour. Does that affect transactional safety?

Comment: BTW since `START TRANSACTION` **is** allowed inside the function why not start the transaction with that instead of `SET autocommit...`?

Comment: To check your autocommit `select @@autocommit`.